# challenge on Nested resources url

Tags: rest, nested-resources

How is a nested resource URL like /bikes/123/reviews
different from an endpoint like /reviews?

I need help I expect to get to know of the difference between a nested resource URL like /bikes/123/reviews
and an endpoint like /reviews?

Answer (score 0):

> How is a nested resource URL like /bikes/123/reviews different from an endpoint like /reviews?

Not very much?

Both are perfectly satisfactory resource identifiers, compliant with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#appendix-A), both are pretty trivially expressed by [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570.html).

One difference between the two spellings is that you can use [dot-segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-5.2.4) to move up the hierarchy of path segments; in other words, you can compute `/bikes/123` from the context `/bikes/123/reviews` and the relative path `..`.

Resource identifiers are a lot like variable names: the machines *don't care*, and that's a good thing because it gives designers the ability to tailor their spelling conventions to make things easier for the people they care about.

---

Example:

```
/questions/78070804/challenge-on-nested-resources-url
/questions/78070804
/challenge-on-nested-resources-url
```

All three of these spellings are *fine*; the web browser would know what do do in each case without difficulty.  The third spelling gives humans context, but risks collisions -- we're allowed to have more than one question with the same hint.  The second spelling has no risks of collisions, but strips away the context.  The first spelling gives the human readers context without risking collisions.

---

That said, a lot of today's conventions about resource models and resource identifiers has its roots in Rails 1.2.  Therefore, it can help to be familiar with

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- https://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources